# Alternative for looping in R

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(Chr=1, Pos= c(100,200,300,400),stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 <- data.frame(Chr=1, PosStart= c(25,25,150,175,225,275,375),PosEnd= c(150,75,275,300,400,500,750),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I am trying to compare the `Pos` values in `df1` to see if the fall between any `PosStart` and `PosEnd` of `df2`. This could be true for more than 1 rows of `df2`. In the output I am trying to append the `df1$Pos` as a new column `df2$CoPos`; each time the condition is true. The output should be someting like:

```
Chr PosStart PosEnd CoPos
1       25    150   100
1      150    275   200
1      175    300   200
1      225    400   300
1      275    500   300
1      375    750   400
```

I have done something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(df1$Pos)){

    for(j in 1:length(df2$PosStart){

            df2$CoPos[j]<- df1$Pos[which(df2$PosStart[j] < df1$Pos[i] < df2$PosEnd[j])]
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me if there is a way to do this without looping. Also what am I doing wrong here? After months of grappling I don't think I still understand the concept of looping.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can `apply` the check to each row of `df2`:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  data.frame(df2[x['Pos'] < df2$PosEnd & x['Pos'] > df2$PosStart,], Pos=x['Pos'])
}
```

Which will return a row or rows from df2 where the condition is met as well as the `Pos` value.

```
> apply(df1, 1, myfun)
[[1]]
  Chr PosStart PosEnd Pos
1   1       25    150 100

[[2]]
  Chr PosStart PosEnd Pos
3   1      150    275 200
4   1      175    300 200

[[3]]
  Chr PosStart PosEnd Pos
5   1      225    400 300
6   1      275    500 300

[[4]]
  Chr PosStart PosEnd Pos
6   1      275    500 400
7   1      375    750 400

>
```

then you can use `plyr` and `ldply` to convert to a list:

```
> library(plyr)
> ldply(apply(df1, 1, myfun), as.data.frame)
  Chr PosStart PosEnd Pos
1   1       25    150 100
2   1      150    275 200
3   1      175    300 200
4   1      225    400 300
5   1      275    500 300
6   1      275    500 400
7   1      375    750 400
>
```

---

Edit for comment:

This is a hard thing to do in a for loop.  You don't know how many matches you'll have in advance.  It could be that every row in `df1` matches every row in `df2` or that none do or anything in between. Thus, you don't know how big your output needs to be.  This is the perfect example of bad `for loop` practice in R.  As in, if you are growing your output vector rather than assigning into it "you're gonna have a bad time mm'kay."

With that said, to make your loop work, you would need to make the `CoPos` column first.

```
df2$CoPos <- NA
```

Then execute something similar to your loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1$Pos)) {
    for (j in 1:length(df2$PosStart)) {
            if (df2$PosStart[j] < df1$Pos[i] & df2$PosEnd[j] > df1$Pos[i]) {
                    df2$CoPos[j] <- df1$Pos[i]
            }
    }

}
```

However, if you find two rows in `df1` that fit your constraint, you'll only record the second one you find into the appropriate row in `df2`.

Instead, you could grow a new data.frame like this:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Chr=1, Pos= c(100, 125, 200,300,400),stringsAsFactors=F)

out <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(df3$Pos)) {
    for (j in 1:length(df2$PosStart)) {
            if (df2$PosStart[j] < df3$Pos[i] & df2$PosEnd[j] > df3$Pos[i]) {
                    out <- rbind(out, cbind(df2[j,], df3$Pos[i]))
            }
    }

}
```

But, don't do this... please don't :)  While I'm evangelizing, take a look at the [R-Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for an excellent reference on common pitfalls in R.

Comment: Or, staying in base R: `do.call(rbind, apply(df1, 1, myfun))`, but base R will not give you the same row names.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! This is amazing!!!!!!!!! It works like a charm and no loops involved, and I completely understand it. I guess R really forces one to think differently. However just for the sake of it could you please tell me where I went wrong with the for loop. I added the & sign between the two conditions.

Comment: @user1079898 see my edit.  Also, if this answer works for you, please mark it as answered so others can tell.

Comment: Hi Hustin...thank you so much....yes I would not do this ...it was just to understand how it may work using the loop.....I really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 3):

While [@Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906490/justin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693602/271616) works in this case, using `apply` on a data.frame can lead to confusing errors if you don't remember that `apply` converts your data.frame to a matrix before calling `FUN` on each row/column.

Here is a more general solution that avoids this potential issue:

```
compareFun <- function(x) {
  data.frame(df2[x > df2$PosStart & x < df2$PosEnd,], Pos=x)
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(df1$Pos, compareFun))
```

To elaborate, if `df1` and `df2` were instead defined with `Chr` being character, Justin's solution would throw an error that doesn't make it clear what caused the problem:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Chr="1", Pos=c(100,200,300,400), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(Chr="1", PosStart=c(25,25,150,175,225,275,375),
  PosEnd=c(150,75,275,300,400,500,750), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
apply(df1, 1, myfun)
# Error in data.frame(df2[x["Pos"] < df2$PosEnd & x["Pos"] > df2$PosStart,  : 
#  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```